# splitting innerHTML content for multiple div with width 750px and height 635px each

Tags: javascript

I need a logic to split `innerHTML` text into multiple `div` containers with fixed height (635px) and width (750px).

The `innerHTML` content will change based on user input:
here I am not able to paste my `innerHTML` content 
it is the combination of html tags, css

```
div style="text-align:center;"><header class="entry-header"
 style="box-sizing:border-box;color:#333333;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',
 HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:22.5px;background-color:#ffffff;">
<h1 class="entry-title" style="box-sizing:border-box;font-size:36px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0.33em;line-height:36px;font-family:klavika-web, 
'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif !important;">
<span style="font-size:small;">.innerHeight()
```

My retirement is

1. Need to put above content into div, in case the above content is overflowing then apply split in such a way that it should fit div
2. Now the remaining content need to put into another div
3. Again if content remaining keep on continuing creating div and inserting innerHTML content

Please help me out resolving this using javascript or Jquery, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use innerHTML because of security issues, *especially* if you are dependent on user input. Use jQuery's `.text()` to accomplish this.
Asides from this, we need your code to answer your question.

Comment: Hey Thanks for response, I'm just using html content because of Font style and line number will varies and decides the Height.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the folowing.
Create a string that contains the new divs that you want, and concatenate the extra content inside them, and then use Jquery to insert that new string.

Something like this  (Psuedo code)

UserString = $("#chosenSelector").innerHTML;
/*  Do whatever manipulation you want to that text here - such as splitting it into two parts.  */

/*  Then use Jquery to construct the new Div (DOM) elements, and stick the text back inside the new divs */

MyNewString = "";
MyNewString = MyNewString + UserString + "

$("#chosenSelector").innerHTML(MyNewString);

Note however that if you want the new divs to expand to include all the text content -- you might need to give the div a class of 'group' and use the "ClearFix" trick.
http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: hi want logic to split innerHTML                                                            UserString = $("#chosenSelector").innerHTML; /* Do whatever manipulation you want to that text here - such as splitting it into two parts. */